# Set default component when dynamic component doesn't exist Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've created a nested dynamic component in vuejs (2) which renders a different component when a user clicks on one of the tabs. The tabs are generated based on json-data. It can happen that json injects a tab name no specific component has been created for (en thus generates an error). In that case I'd like to render a default component. How can I do this?
I've stripped all irrelvant code and renamed items that is "sensitive info".

So for example: what if json spits out a tab named Seven. Component-seven doesn't exist. How can I make sure component-default renders instead.

```
<template>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h3>
                <span>          
                    Card title
                </span>
            </h3>               
        </div>          

        <div class="card-block" v-if="pageDataLoaded">

            <div class="menu">
                <div>
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs flex-container">
                        <li v-for="(item, index) in items" 
                            :key="items.itemnumber"
                            @click="currentTab = index"
                            class="nav-item">
                            <a v-bind:class="['nav-link', { active: currentTab === index }]">
                                {{ item.itemname }}
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>          

            <!-- content -->
            <component
                    :is = "currentTabComponent"
            ></component>
        </div>  
    </div> 
    </template>

    <script> 

    import componentOne from './one.vue'
    import componentTwo from './two.vue'
    import ComponentThree from './three.vue'
    import ComponentFour from './four.vue'
    import ComponentFive from './five.vue'
    import ComponentSix from './six.vue'
    import ComponentDefault from './default.vue'


    export default {
      name: 'component',
      components: {
          'component-one': componentOne,
          'component-two': componentTwo,
          'component-three': ComponentThree,
          'component-four': ComponentFour,
          'component-five': ComponentFive,
          'component-six': ComponentSix,
          'component-default' : SchadeprocesDefault
      },
      props: {    
        ctx: String
      },
      data: function () {
        return {        
            currentTab: 0,
            items: [],
            pageDataLoaded: false
         }
      },
        methods: {
          selectedTab () {
            var self = this;
            self.currentTab = this.selected;
            return self.currentTab
        }
      },
      mounted: function () {        
        var self = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: this.ctx + "/services/items/getall",
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(items) {
                self.items= items;  
                self.pageDataLoaded = true;     
            },
            error: function() {
                $('#error').html('<p>Nothing found.</p>');
            }
        }); 
      },
      computed: {
        currentTabComponent: function () {
          return 'schadeproces-' + this.polissen[this.currentTab].itemname

        }
      }

    }

    </script>
```

Comment: `<component
                    :is = "currentTabComponent || defaultComponent"
            ></component>`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but by trying this currentTabComponent throws an error and the default doesn't get shown. I guess I need to use a Promise here, but don't know how... or very simple: a check whether a component exists or not. If, then do default.

Comment: Solved this by refatoring the code after receiving an answer here: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/set-default-component-when-dynamic-component-doesnt-exist/42497/2

Comment: Would be great if u answered ur own question then. I nearly overlooked your comment with the link. It solves the question. So i would find it acceptable as an answer. Thank you also for asking and referring to the solution.